# Odd result when bit shifting in Java

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to isolate two bytes that are next to each other add them, but there seems to be an extra bit that sometimes shows up and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. It's throwing off the answer. 
The code is:

```
(acc & 0x00000000ff000000L) + ((acc << 8) & 0x00000000ff000000L);
```

and I'm getting results such as

```
0x0000000147000000
```

when it should be

```
0x0000000047000000
```

How can I get rid of the 1?

Edit: acc is a long. I'm try to add the 5th and 6th byte and then that value will go into a new long in the 5th byte position.

Comment: Can you clarify? What is the value and type of `acc`? What is `0000000147000000`? Do you mean the decimal value `147000000`?

Comment: Everything in Java is done with int. If you bit shift a byte you are bit shifting an int. Are you taking this into consideration?

Comment: A reproducible example would be best.

Comment: The code does indeed sum the 5th and 6th bytes (if you count from the msb), and apparently the result was greater than 255. You could throw in an other AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mask the bits you want at the end, because the addition may carry a bit:

```
((acc & 0x00000000ff000000L) + ((acc << 8) & 0x00000000ff000000L)) & 0x00000000ff000000L;
```

I think this might be clearer if you broke it down a little:

```
acc&=0x00000000FFFF000000L; // isolate bytes 5 and 4
acc+=(acc<<8);              // add the two bytes (we'll strip bytes 6 & 4 next)
acc&=0x00000000FF00000000L; // reduce to byte 5 only
```

which happens to be one less bitwise opperation too.

Comment: Okay. I tried the | instead of + answer you had earlier and it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that's because I misread your intent and jumped to the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the value of the 5th and 6th byte, add them together, and store them in a new long that contains just that sum in the 5th byte. This would be done like this:

```
long 5thByte = acc & 0xff00000000 >>> 32;
long 6thByte = acc & 0xff0000000000 >>> 40;
long sum = 5thByte + 6thByte;
long longWithNewByte = sum << 32;
```

This will of course carryover to the 6th byte if the sum is higher than 255. To get rid of that carryover, you can use another mask.

```
long longWithNewByte &= 0xff00000000;
```

Comment: All of the bitwise `&` operations are wrong; 0xF masks a *nibble* (4 bits), not a *byte* (8 bits). Working off that same incorrect understanding, the shifts are wrong by `2x`. Even if they bits were properly counted, the code still would overshift by 1 byte (to move byte 2 in to byte 1's position, you shift by 8, not 16).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer, I think it's correct now.